# Designing folder/file system?

Tags: c++, class-design

I'm trying to create a folder/file system similar to the ones used in most OSes.
Basically I've figured out that I should use three classes; `File`, `Folder`, and a common base class. Let's call it `Common` for the sake of creativity.
Here's how I thought the headers for those three should look like:

#### common.h

```
class Common {
    string m_name; // all files and folders have a name
    Folder* m_parent; // all files and folders can have a parent

public:
    virtual void open() = 0; // executed when folder or file is opened by user
    virtual void draw() const; // all files and folders can be printed
    virtual void setParent(Folder* parent);
    virtual Folder* getParent() const;
};
```

#### folder.h

```
class Folder : public Common {
    vector<Common*> m_children; // folders can contain other files and folders
                                // whereas files cannot

public:
    virtual void open(); // folder opens; basically shows the content
    virtual void draw() const; // folder draws differently
};
```

#### file.h

```
class File : public Common {
    // not really "files", they just call a function when opened
    funcptr m_openAction;

public:
    virtual void open(); // calls m_openAction() when opened
};
```

As you can see, the problem is that my base class `Common` should be able to know it's subclass `Folder`, which is bad behaviour and shouldn't be done (at least according to my teacher).
This makes it impossible for me to code the system like I had planned to.

How should such system be designed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your existing design does *not* require `Common` to "know its subclass `Folder`".
It just requires the `Common` header to declare that *there is some such class*
as `Folder`:

```
class Folder; // Forward declaration

class Common {
    string m_name; // all files and folders have a name
    Folder* m_parent; // all files and folders can have a parent

public:
    virtual ~Common(); // Don't forget virtual destructor!
    virtual void open() = 0; // executed when folder or file is opened by user
    virtual void draw() const; // all files and folders can be printed
    virtual void setParent(Folder* parent);
    virtual Folder* getParent() const;
};
```

There is no dependency cycle here.

If for some academic reason you must have a base class that does not even
*mention* any subclass then you can make the polymorphic base class like this:

```
class Node {
    string m_name; // all files and folders have a name
    Node* m_parent; // all files and folders can have a parent

public:
    virtual ~Node(); // Don't forget virtual destructor!
    virtual void open() = 0; // executed when folder or file is opened by user
    virtual void draw() const; // all files and folders can be printed
    virtual void setParent(Node* parent);
    virtual Node* getParent() const;
};
```

With this design however the `setParent(Node* parent)` method will have
to include a runtime check that the `Node *` argument `parent` is in fact a
`Folder *`, using e.g.

```
Folder *pf = dynamic_cast<Folder *>(parent);
```

and in that case it would also require a non-void return type by which to
indicate success or failure. This is tortuous as opposed to merely making a
declaration of `class Folder`.

**CONTINUED** to address OP's follow-up question.

> Inside Common's `setParent()` I have to call Folder's m_children; which results into an error. Even if I include folder.h in common.cpp, I can't access folder's private members. Any ideas? :'

My foregoing answer was limited to showing you that what "makes it impossible for you to code the system like you had planned to"
actually doesn't.

The problem you see now is that setting some folder `f` as the parent of some
node `n` is not an independant operation on a node (file-or-folder). `f` can only
validly become the parent of `n` if `n` simultaneously becomes one of the
children of `f`. Thus in `n.setParent(parent)`, at the same time as setting
`n.mParent == parent` you wish to add `n` to `parent->m_children`; 
but `m_children` is inaccessible to the node `n`.

This problem is a heavy hint for your design. If setting-the-parent and adding-the-child
must always occur together then they are effectively the same operation - set-parent-add-child
- just invoked differently: from the parent or from the child. If there is a 
reason for `Common` to provide `setParent(Folder *)` then there is equally good 
reason for `Folder` to provide `addChild(Common *)`, and they must both do the same thing.

Does this suggest that, say, `static void Common::link(Folder * parent, Common * child)` 
might better publically replace them both? Maybe so; but you started out with 
`Common::setParent(Folder *)`,
which was reasonable; so matching it with `Folder::addChild(Common *)` is reasonable too,
and then we may get them to do the same thing by invoking *each other*.

Consider also, then, that since `pCommon->setParent(pFolder)` is
equivalent to `pFolder->addChild(pCommon)`, you also need the means of
*removing* a node from its parent; because before you can validly add
a node to a parent you must remove it from its existing parent, if any. And
this operation will very likely be a boon to client code; so
`Folder::removeChild(Common *)` is also a natural addition to the
`Folder` interface.

`Folder::addChild(Common * pnode)` and `Folder::removeChild(Common * pnode)` are
the interfaces you are lacking to manage the private member `Folder::m_children`.

Next, consider that each of these methods is going to have to
determine whether `pnode` is in fact a child of the folder: you must not add
a child to a folder where it is already a child, and you cannot remove a child that isn't one.
So `Folder::find(Common * pnode)` will also be useful - at least to the implementation
(private), and plausibly also to client code (public): you can decide.

Then, consider that `Folder::find(Common * pnode)` calls for 
another method: `bool Common::operator==(Common const & other)`. Let's just say that
nodes are equal if they have the same name.

`Common::clearParent()` also springs to mind, but I will set that aside.

These ideas suffice for the following implementation, which is 
incomplete, suboptimal and impractical, but shows how you can join up the dots we have
just identified so as to pass through the member-access obstacle that is
still stopping you. It is impractical because it ignores 
the whole matter of the ownership of the dynamic objects that are assumed to 
be addressed by the `Folder *` and `Common *` arguments of its methods. 
You can deal with that yourself (and you may wish to investigate
[std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and 
[std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), even if 
these are more
advanced facilities than you are supposed to use in this project).

**common.h**

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#include <string>

#include <iostream>

class Folder;

class Common {
    std::string m_name;
    Folder* m_parent;

public:
    explicit Common(std::string const & name)
    : m_name(name),m_parent(nullptr){}
    virtual ~Common(){};
    virtual void open() { /*Whatever*/}
    virtual void draw() const {/*Whatever*/}
    virtual Folder* getParent() const { return m_parent; };
    virtual void setParent(Folder* parent);
    bool operator==(Common const & other) const {
        return m_name == other.m_name;
    }
    bool operator!=(Common const & other) const {
        return !(*this  == other);
    }
#if 1 // Testing
    std::string const & name() const {
        return m_name;
    }
    std::string parent() const;

    virtual void list() const {
        std::cout << name() << " (in " << parent() << ')' << std::endl ;
    }
#endif
};

#endif // EOF
```

**folder.h**

```
#ifndef FOLDER_H
#define FOLDER_H

#include "common.h"
#include <vector>

class Folder : public Common {
    std::vector<Common *> m_children;

    std::vector<Common *>::iterator find(Common const * child) {
        auto i = m_children.begin();
        for (   ;i != m_children.end() && **i != *child; ++i) {}
        return i;
    }

public:
    explicit Folder(std::string const & name)
    : Common(name){}
    virtual void open(){/*Whatever*/}
    virtual void draw() const {/*Whatever*/}
    void addChild(Common * child) {
        auto par = child->getParent();
        if (par && par != this) {
            par->removeChild(child);
        }
        if (find(child) == m_children.end()) {
            m_children.push_back(child);
            m_children.back()->setParent(this);
        }
    }
    void removeChild(Common const * child) {
        auto where = find(child);
        if (where != m_children.end()) {
            m_children.erase(where);
        }
    }
#if 1 // Testing
    void list() const {
        std::cout << name() << " {" << std::endl;
        for (Common const * child : m_children) {
            child->list();
        }
        std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
    }
#endif
};

#endif //EOF
```

**file.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#include "common.h"

class File : public Common {
    // Whatever
public:
    explicit File(std::string const & name)
    : Common(name){}
    virtual void open(){/*Whatever*/};

};

#endif // EOF
```

**common.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"
#include "folder.h"

void Common::setParent(Folder* parent) {
    auto par = getParent();
    if (par && par != parent) {
        par->removeChild(this);
    }
    m_parent = parent;
    m_parent->addChild(this);
}

#if 1 // Testing
std::string Common::parent() const {
    return m_parent ? m_parent->name() : "<null>";
}
#endif
```

A test program:

```
#include "common.h"
#include "folder.h"
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
    Folder *fo0 = new Folder("folder0");
    File * fi0 = new File("file0");
    File * fi1 = new File("file1");
    fo0->addChild(fi0);
    fi1->setParent(fo0);
    fo0->addChild(fi0);  // Duplicate
    fi1->setParent(fo0); // Duplicate
    // There are now 2 files in folder fo0
    fo0->list();
    Folder *fo1 = new Folder("folder1");
    fo1->addChild(fi1);
    fi0->setParent(fo1);
    fo1->addChild(fi1); // Duplicate
    fi0->setParent(fo1); // Duplicate
    // There are now 0 files in folder fo0
    // There are now 2 files in folder fo1
    fo0->list();
    fo1->list();
    delete fo0;
    delete fo1;
    delete fi0;
    delete fi1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but doesn't solve all my problems. Inside Common's `setParent()` I have to call Folder's `m_children;` which results into an error. Even if I include `folder.h` in `common.cpp`, I can't access folder's private members. Any ideas? :'>

Comment: Because Folder derives from Common, you can use `dynamic_cast<Folder*>` to cast a `Common*` to a `Folder*`. If it cannot be done (e.g. because it is a File), you'll get a `nullptr` back.

Comment: Of course, your teacher is going to complain about your use of RTTI in that case ;-)

Comment: Thank you *so much* for your effort, I learned *a lot* from your answer! Besides, I got my program working now thanks to you! ^^ If I could, I would upvote this approximately 400 000 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t put a folder inside common and make an inheritance of common in folder; it´s a cyclic redundancy error.

This system could be designed with two classes only: file and folder, but if you want to make a generalization, remove folder from common.

Comment: This doesn't really help at all, I already knew I can't do what I did, and you "solution" doesn't really make any sense... Could you explain with more detail?

Comment: @mazoti. "cyclic redundancy" is not what you mean. That is something entirely different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check